# What is the meaning of "I read is"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *Glass (2019)* movie, Elijah's mom is talking about his son:

> Elijah's mom: He has this notion that superheroes are based on people
>   like him, and that other gentleman **I read is** here, Mr. Dunn.
>
> Dr Ellie: Would it surprise you to know there are more and more people
>   who have this delusion? It is actually the center of my work
>
> Elijah's mom: Yes, it would.

Comment: You sure you got the words correct?

Comment: @CinCout I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are taking this from a script or transcribing it yourself, but the first obvious thing to point out is that "read" can be both the present *and* past tense, as they are *spelled* the same but *pronounced* differently. If this is "read" in the past tense then Elijah's mom is saying that "he" (Elijah) believes superheroes are based on people like himself and Mr Dunn, whom Elijah's mom has read is also here in the hospital. She knows Elijah is there because he is her son and she has been brought there to discuss him, but she is only aware of Dunn's presence there because she read it somewhere.

Also though, "I read" (in the present tense) can be used to refer to things you have read (past) in the same way that "I hear" can be used to refer to things you have *heard*. In this case it would essentially mean the same as I suggested above.